# $(...).fullCalendar is not a function - Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, webpack

When I try to load the calendar the webpack compiler does not seem to recognize jquery is being used? I am following the [basic usage](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/) guide

I assume because full calendar has jquery bundled in already I do not need to call it.

In my `app.js` I am calling fullCalendar via

```
import fullCalendar from 'fullCalendar';
const calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');

$(calendar).fullCalendar();
```

I know I am doing something wrong and I could not find any import methods inside the full calendar docs.

Comment: It may be that you are switching between pure javascript and jquery. You should use one or the other. Try creating your calendar using $('#calendar') instead

Comment: Justin is right, `getElementById` returns an HTML DOM element, while jQuery's `$(...)` returns a jQuery object

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the reply. I switched to your method and I'm still resulting in the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use fullcalendar with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321399/use-fullcalendar-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

1) Install via npm (`npm install fullcalendar --save-dev`)

2) In webpack.config.js have following

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'fullcalendar',
        ...
   ]
}
```

3) In your javascript

```
require("fullcalendar"); //maybe import works as well
$calendar.fullCalendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

With webpack 5. below code solves my issue,

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options:  { 
                        exposes: ["$", "jQuery"]
                    }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('moment'),
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options:  { 
                        exposes: "moment"
                    }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('fullcalendar'),
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'script-loader',
                      options: 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'
                    }
                  ]
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('fullcalendar-scheduler'),
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'script-loader',
                      options: 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar-scheduler.js'
                    }
                  ]
            },
        ]
    }
```