# Use fullcalendar with webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, fullcalendar

I use npm, webpack and FullCalendar, but I get the following error in the browser console when using fullcalendar:

```
main.js:37556 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

How do I fix this?

I use FullCalendar 3.0.0-beta and jquery 3.1.0. My code is below.

**index.js:**

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jQueryUI from 'jquery-ui'
import moment from 'moment'
import fullCalendar from 'fullcalendar'


$('#timetable').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    droppable: true,
})
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require("webpack")
var BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker")

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        'fullcalendar',
        './static/index',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
    ],

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js'],
    },

    module: {
        loaders:[
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel', query: { presets: ['es2015'] } }
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have bower?

Comment: @Anokrize No I use npm.

Answer (score 9):

I know I am somewhat late to the party here, but I thought I'd answer anyway in case somebody hits this up on Google.

Whenever I run into a jQuery Plugin with Webpack (which FullCalendar is), I need to make sure that jQuery itself is exposed to the global namespace before the plugin will work through require/import.

My webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack")
var path = require("path")
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./index.js",
        vendor: [
            "jquery",
            "moment",
            "fullcalendar"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../../public'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "scripts/app.[chunkhash].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", ["css"]) },
            { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery' },
            { test: require.resolve('moment'), loader: 'expose?moment' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        jquery: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'node_modules', 'jquery')),
        fullcalendar: 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar'
      }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: ["vendor"], filename: "scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js" }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/[name].[chunkhash].css"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "index.html.handlebars"
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/) 
    ]
};
```

The relevant part is where jquery and moment are forced to be in the global namespace via the `loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery'` syntax.

Second, because fullcalendar is packaged in a way that the require can't automatically pick it up, I setup an alias so that I can have a clean package name. This is the `alias: { fullcalendar: 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar' }` bit.

These two let me load fullcalendar via require/import and use it as I normally would.

The styles also need to be loaded. For this one I have not created aliases yet, so I just did a relative path to the css file:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css";
```

You can replace `fullcalendar.js` with `fullcalendar.min.js` to avoid recompressing, but for my use case because I was bundling all the vendor JS files together, I thought I would get better compression if I had more files concatenated. (Ditto for CSS `fullcalendar.css` with `fullcalendar.min.css`)

Disclaimer: I don't know if this is the "correct" way of doing this, but I know it took me a fair bit of trial and error with webpack to get jQuery plug ins like FullCalendar and Select2 to work, and this shell and method did make it easy.

For reference, links to the relevant files in a public repo where I use this pattern:

webpack.config.js: https://github.com/thegrandpoobah/mftk-back-office/blob/e531de0a94130d6e9634ba5ab547a3e4d41c5c5f/app/src/public/webpack.config.js

style scss: https://github.com/thegrandpoobah/mftk-back-office/blob/e531de0a94130d6e9634ba5ab547a3e4d41c5c5f/app/src/public/styles/main.scss

module where I use fullcalendar: https://github.com/thegrandpoobah/mftk-back-office/blob/e531de0a94130d6e9634ba5ab547a3e4d41c5c5f/app/src/public/students/index.js#L277

Comment: What ended up being your overall bundle size? My bundle size when doing it with webpack shot up about 450KB when I added jquery/fullcalendar into the mix

Comment: My vendor bundle size is 1.65 MB when compressed using uglify. It contains jquery, lodash, aviator, handlebars, moment, alpaca, a datetimepicker for bootstrap, modernizr, and fullcalendar. Without fullcalendar it would be 1.51 MB. The fullcalendar zip file you download off the fullcalendar.io website has the minified version at 213.8 KB. My numbers aren't exact here, but it seems to at the very least be inline with the official package. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is a step by step guide based on the data from above and other sources. First make sure you have moment.js installed:

```
npm install moment
```

Then make sure you have the fullcalendar version 3.10.2, which is the latest in version 3 which is optimized not bundling jQuery nor moment.js , and although it's not the latest version, it uses the old syntax, which won't break compatibility with legacy code:

```
npm install fullcalendar@3.10.2
```

Then install script-loader

```
npm install --save-dev script-loader
```

If you are using Laravel, then in resources/js/bootstrap.js add the following lines below bootstrap and jquery (note the use of script-lader!) :

```
window.moment = require('moment');
require('script-loader!fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar');
require('script-loader!fullcalendar/dist/locale-all');
```

Then add the css style in resources/sass/app.scss:

```
@import '~fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css';
```

Finally do:

```
npm run dev
```

Or, for production:

```
npm run prod
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an even easier solution.

We're using fullcalendar and scheduler. We're converting from Rails sprockets to webpack. Adding fullcalendar to a lazyloaded chunk with webpack caused it to introduce two additional moments and jquerys (yep two) which, of course, didn't pick up our configuration changes as those where done on the original version in our chunked vendor file.

Ideally we just wanted fullcalendar included with no module processing (it does absolutely nothing and is totally unnecessary). Fortunately you can do this with webpack's script-loader.

```
require('script-loader!fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js')
```

And you're done. Same with the scheduler. It loads it in isolation and unprocessed which is exactly what you want with a jquery plugin.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, migrating from Rails assets pipelines to Webpack, I tried this, but I have the error "[Script Loader] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". How do you deal with that?

Comment: I actually solved my issue using the expose-loader in order to expose jQuery as jQuery and $ and to expose moment, which solved my issue.

Comment: Yes, exposing those is the way to go, although even better is to upgrade fullCalendar to the one without the jQuery dependency. We've largely completed our migration so no more hacks required. Sprockets is still serving CSS for the time being but otherwise that's it.

Answer (score 0):

With webpack 5, below code solves the issue:

```
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options:  { 
                        exposes: ["$", "jQuery"]
                    }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('moment'),
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options:  { 
                        exposes: "moment"
                    }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('fullcalendar'),
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'script-loader',
                      options: 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'
                    }
                  ]
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('fullcalendar-scheduler'),
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'script-loader',
                      options: 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar-scheduler.js'
                    }
                  ]
            },
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

I used **fullCalendar** for example:

```
$("#fullcalendar-activities").fullCalendar({
        header: {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        events: events,
        defaultView: 'month'
 });
```